# How to use begin() and end() in a ranged for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

Why doesn't this code work?

The error I'm getting is

```
T *Vector<T>::begin(Vector<T> &)' : expects 1 arguments - 0 provided
```

code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<typename T> class Vector
{
public:

    T* elem;
    int sz;

    Vector()
    {
        elem = new T[2];
        sz = 2;
    }

    template<typename T> T* begin(Vector<T>& x)
    {
        return &x[0];
    }

    template<typename T> T* end(Vector<T>& x)
    {
        return x.begin()+x.size();
    }

    unsigned int size()
    {
        return sz;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector<int> ea;

    for(auto& s: ea)
        // do something

    return 0;
}
```

also I'm not sure of the vector parameter to begin() and end(), why do they need it? They're already member functions so they should have "this" as parameter. I wrote this code but the functions are taken from a book (are they friend??)

Comment: `template<typename T> T* begin()`, perhaps?

Comment: The book is in your hands, why are you asking us? The look like they are meant to be free functions.

Comment: (Or better, `T& begin()`? If that's permitted...)

Comment: @H2CO3 I think it needs to return something that is at least a forward iterator. `T*` satisfies that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `Vector::begin()` and `Vector::end()` *(without parameters)*. And the returned values should work as iterators.

This could be a similar possible implementation for ranged-based loop:

```
auto && __range = range_expression;
for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin)
{
    range_declaration = *__begin;
    // loop_statement
}
```

Therefore:

> If __range's type is a class type with either or both a begin or an
>   end member function, then begin_expr is **__range.begin()** and end_expr
>   is **__range.end()**; <sup>[1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)</sup>

So, it should be:

```
T* begin()
{
    return elem;
}

T* end()
{
    return elem + sz;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
template<typename T> T* begin()
{
    return &elem[0];
}

template<typename T> T* end()
{
    return begin() + size;
}
```

Comment: `template<typename T>` should not be included here; these declarations are already inside the class template.